# Accessing JSON fields using PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm setting up a webhook handler that receives a POST. Since I'm not storing the data in a database for this, I'm just having the data print to a text file to see what everything is, using

```
file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/response.txt", $test_file, FILE_APPEND);
```

$_POST['data_json']; returns the following object

> {    "time_submitted":[
> "11:47 PM UTC"    ],    "page_uuid":[
> "657773c0-596b-4cad-b2f6-7e1e197f4df4"    ],    "phone_number":[
> "3335553344"    ],    "estimated_move_date":[
> "09/29/2020"    ],    "email":[
> "toweltest@test.com"    ],    "page_name":[
> "Test Page"    ],    "utm_adgroup":[
> ""    ],    "date_submitted":[
> "2020-09-16"    ],    "name":[
> "toweltest"    ],    "source":[
> "AdWords"    ],    "utm_campaign":[
> ""    ],    "ip_address":[
> "33.333.333.333"    ],    "page_url":[
> "http://testurl.com/"    ],    "utm_term":[
> ""    ],    "variant":[
> "a"    ] }

So I set $_POST['data_json'] to a variable

```
$test_file = $_POST['data_json'];
```

and I try to print $test_file->email to the file, but nothing prints.

```
$email = $test_file->email;
file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/response.txt", $email, FILE_APPEND);
```

I've been encoding and decoding and trying to figure out what's wrong with my format. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if your post data is $test_file = $_POST['data_json'];

$data = json_decode($test_file);
$email = $data->email;
file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/response.txt", $email, FILE_APPEND);
```

If you still see the issue, check for directory permissions.

Comment: Thank you!!! is there a reason $data->email; returns what I need, but $data just returns "ArrayArrayArray"?

Comment: In this case, once you decode your JSON $data contains a multidimensional array. If you want to print the entire array you can use this below code


$data = json_decode($test_file);
file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/response.txt", print_r($data, true), FILE_APPEND);

Answer (score 0):

Source:

```
$dataJsonStr = $_POST['data_json'];
$data = json_decode($dataJsonStr);
var_dump($data->email);
var_dump($data->email[0]);
```

Result:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "toweltest@test.com"
}
string(18) "toweltest@test.com"
```

The original $data->email is an array, it may contains multiple items. Be sure you inspect the array before use.